# Understanding what is going on under the hood of Mockito framework

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a problem understanding what is going on in the Mockito framework here. I have the following classes

Model class

```
public class KeyValueImpl{

    private String key;
    private String value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

"business logic" class

```
public class ValueFinder {

    public KeyValueImpl findValueForKey(KeyValueImpl keyValue){
        keyValue.setValue("foo");
        return keyValue;
    }

}
```

Utility class to return the expected result (will be mocked)

```
public class ExpectationManager {

    public String getExpectedValue(){
        return "loremipsumdolorem";
    }

}
```

Test class

```
public class ValueFinderTest {

    @Test
    public void testMocked() {
        KeyValueImpl keyValue = Mockito.mock(KeyValueImpl.class);
        keyValue = (new ValueFinder()).findValueForKey(keyValue);
        ExpectationManager expectationManager = Mockito.mock(ExpectationManager.class);
        when(expectationManager.getExpectedValue()).thenReturn("somethingDifferentToFoo");
        String expectedValue = expectationManager.getExpectedValue();
        verify(keyValue).setValue(expectedValue);  //fails, expects "foo" but gets "somethingDifferentToFoo" -> ok
        verify(keyValue).setValue(expectationManager.getExpectedValue());  //no error, but why?
    }

}
```

The interesting thing happens in the last row of the test class:

```
verify(keyValue).setValue(expectationManager.getExpectedValue());  //no error, but why?
```

I would certainly  expect the same behaviour like in the row above

```
verify(keyValue).setValue(expectedValue);  //fails, expects "foo" but gets somethingDifferentToFoo" -> ok
```

However Mockito let's me get along with it. Any explantation for this?

Comment: Your `ValueFinder` class doesn't use `ExpectationManager` at all, so why is that involved in your test? What are you actually trying to test here?

Comment: I am using it within my Test class. The expectationManager returns the value which I use in my verify method. Everything is boiled down in this example for the sake of simplicity

Comment: Um, but why - isn't the point that you're testing your *production* code? You say you're going to mock the ExpectationManager... when you start mocking out classes which are only there for tests in the first place, that sounds very wrong to me...

Comment: In my productive environment the ExpectationManager is actually a real object used in productive code (not only in tests). And for technical reasons beyond my control I **do have** to mock it. Don't bother about the architecture here :-) It boils down to the question: Why do the two lines of code produce different results?

Comment: Are you actually making both of those verify calls in one test run, or do you effectively have two different methods? Given that you've got two mocks involved here, which is failing? I can't help but think you could simplify your example by having a single mock... and ideally only making a single *call* to a mock per statement.

Comment: I have two differnt methods. The line `verify(keyValue).setValue(expectedValue);` fails (AssertionError) which is exactly what I expect. But If I pass in the mocked object in the verify method `verify(keyValue).setValue(expectationManager.getExpectedValue()); ` I don't get an assertion error which is weird.

Comment: Okay, I'm still slightly confused by the whole thing, but I suspect I have an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is due to the order of the calls. Your last line is effectively:

```
KeyValueImpl tmp = verify(keyValue);
String value = expectationManager.getExpectedValue();
tmp.setValue(value);
```

*If* Mockito is effectively using the `verify` method call as a marker to say "the next time a mocked method gets called, check it" without validating which mock it's called on, then it'll be the `expectationManager.getExpectedValue()` call that is verified.

While I would argue this is confusing behaviour in Mockito, I'd *also* argue that it's a confusing test - using one mock within the verification step of another feels like a design smell to me. I'd strongly consider using manually-written fakes rather than mocks where possible, simply to avoid too much interaction between mocks.

Comment: What is the difference between a fake and a mock?

Comment: Hi Jon, yes, I think this is explaining the problem and aswers my question. I also agree regarding your point, that waht I am trying to do is a bit of a confusing design. I will try to avoid this as far as I can. Thanks again, Paul